# Typescript function notation

Tags: typescript

In typescript what is the difference for two function type declaration notations

```
(a: string) => void
(a: string): void
```

Initially I thought it's just a matter of using the arrow function or not.
But seems they are not quite interchangeable since in different cases compiler might reject either of them and accept the other one. And vice versa.

Comment: First one is much safer to use than second one. Second one `(a: string): void` is bivariant, which is not safe. You can find an explanation in TS docs if you write `bivariant` in search input

Comment: Can you post a [mre] of what you mean about the compiler rejecting/accepting?  They are different in that `(a: string) => void` is a type by itself, but `(a: string): void` is not, and needs to be included in an object type like `{(a: string): void}` to be a type.  If you're asking about the difference between `(a: string) => void` and `{(a: string): void}`, there isn't much of one.  @captain-yossarian said one is bivariant, [but I don't think so](https://tsplay.dev/WGkM9W); only *method syntax* is always bivariant, and call signatures look similar but are not.